# XML Schema that allows embedding html

Tags: xml, xsd

In my xml schema I have a tag named itemsetting:

```
    <xs:element name="itemsetting">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="key" use="required">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="questionscript"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="timeframe"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="textlabel"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="textboxtype"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

What I would like to do is to be able to embed html into a questionscript type.  For example:

```
<itemsetting key="questionscript">this<html:b>is bold </html:b> </itemsetting>
```

I've tried to fiddle with the complex/simple times and each time I end up with a schema file that is unable to be parsed.  A pointer in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't wrap the contents in a CDATA tag? Example: `<![CDATA[ <b>bold!</b> ]]>`

Comment: There are a zillion reasons why you wouldn't want to do that - CDATA is for character data, not for nested markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on Michael's answer, something like this:

```
<xs:element name="itemsetting">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="key" use="required">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="questionscript"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="timeframe"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="textlabel"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="textboxtype"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

should work - assuming `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` is the HTML namespace corresponding to the `html` prefix in your XML.

If you have multiple namespaces, or you don't want to bother with namespace checking use

```
 . . . 
      <xs:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
 . . .
```

Note that this assumes that the embedded HTML is well-formed XML, if - for example - it contains not closed tags that will make the whole XML file unreadable, and there is no way to use a schema then.

Answer (score 2):

Your element doesn't have simple content: it contains child elements, which means it is complex content (specifically, `<complexContent mixed="true">`).

If you want to allow any child element in the HTML namespace, you can achieve that by defining a content model with a single wildcard particle `<xs:any namespace="..." minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>`

Comment: When I change the third tag down to simpleContent to <complexContent mixed="true"> and try to validate an xml file that hasn't changed I get the 'unable to parse schema'.  Also, I do not know where the 'any namespace' tag would best go.

Comment: I'm not going to write the code for you. I've given you enough information to find the answer in any textbook. Are you using a decent schema editor?